# In angular 2 the RouterOutlet seems to have changed with the new library for @router does anyone know what to?

Tags: angularjs, angular

In angular 2 the RouterOutlet  seems to have changed with the new library for @router does anyone know what to?

I'm using angular 2 with typescript.

My code below redirects the user to home view if they are not logged in when trying to reach a page that requires login.

Since I've updated my library for @angular/router. it seems to stop working and the console doesnt give me a readable message but I'm assuming the **RouterOutlet** has changed or the **ComponentInstruction**.

**These are my angular2 dependencies:**

```
         @angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.1",
```

**I've added my code below:**

import {Directive, Attribute, ElementRef, DynamicComponentLoader} from '@angular2/core';
    import {Router, RouterOutlet, ComponentInstruction} from '@angular2/router';

```
import {Environment} from './models/environment/environment';

@Directive({
  selector: 'router-outlet'
})

export class LoggedInRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
  publicRoutes: any;
  private parentRouter: Router;
  environment: Environment;

  constructor(_elementRef: ElementRef, _loader: DynamicComponentLoader, _parentRouter: Router, @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string, _environment: Environment) {
    super(_elementRef, _loader, _parentRouter, nameAttr);

    this.parentRouter = _parentRouter;
    this.environment = _environment;

    this.publicRoutes = [
      'home',
      'contact',
      'forgotpassword',
      'socialRegister',
      'login',
      'register/',
      'register/:id',
      'blog/:slug',
      'blog',
      'sitemap',
      'newJobs',
      'newJob/:slug'
    ];
  }

  activate(instruction: ComponentInstruction) { 
     var ref = new Firebase(this.environment.firebaseUrl);

     var authToken = ref.getAuth();  
     var isPublicRoute = this.publicRoutes.indexOf(instruction.urlPath) > -1;
     var registerRouter = instruction.urlPath.substring(0, 8) === "register";
     var socialRegister = instruction.urlPath.substring(0, 14) === "socialRegister";
     var blogRouter = instruction.urlPath.substring(0, 4) === "blog";
     var newJobRouter = instruction.urlPath.substring(0, 6) === "newJob";

     if(authToken == null && !isPublicRoute && !registerRouter && !socialRegister && !blogRouter && !newJobRouter)
        this.parentRouter.navigate(['/Home']);

     return super.activate(instruction); 
  }

}
```

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9059

Comment: So basically I cannot extend RouterOutlet like in router-deprecated?

Comment: Overall, what I'm trying to achieve is to detect the route name in a global place in my code and redirect the user before it hits the component. In the past it would hit the component and cause all types of errors.

Comment: Currently not. You should stay away from `@angular/router` anyway. It will be replaced soon (again). Rather stick with `@angular/router-deprecated`.

Comment: hmm I have no choice at the moment

Comment: You can import the `RouterOutlet` class from `@angular/router/src/...` (don't know exactly)

Comment: Is there another way to achieve the same outcome? Meaning, I want to globally detect route change before hitting the routes component so I can quickly redirect them back to the homepage?

Comment: Hardly. Lifecycle events are also mostly not implemented in the new router as far as I know.

Comment: What I'm doing in a similar situation is using a `LoginService` injected into each component. Call the service in `routerOnActivate` with the current segment/tree or other requirements. If permitted, initialize the component in `routerOnActivate`, otherwise redirect. I'm also using a boolean flag on the `LoginService` to hide the entire component until the user is identified.

Comment: I see. Could you add your example of this below?

Comment: import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router/src/directives/router_outlet';

trying to convert the same example. I'm using angular-cli, so I'm forced to use @angular/router. Not having much luck.

Comment: would love to see this converted to the new router.

https://auth0.com/blog/2015/05/14/creating-your-first-real-world-angular-2-app-from-authentication-to-calling-an-api-and-everything-in-between/

Comment: Does this look right: import {RouterOutlet} from '@angular/router/src/directives/router_outlet';

Comment: yes it looks right

Comment: I'm getting this console error though: No provider for RouterOutletMap!

Comment: import { Router, RouterOutletMap } from '@angular/router';

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have so far:

**my-app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MeComponent } from './+me';
import { Routes , Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router';
import { LoggedInRouterOutlet } from './utilities/loggedinoutlet.directive';
import { LoginComponent } from './+login';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app-app',
  templateUrl: 'my-app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['my-app.component.css'],
  directives: [LoggedInRouterOutlet],
  providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
@Routes([
  {path: '/me', component: MeComponent},
  {path: '/login', component: LoginComponent}
])
export class MyAppAppComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router){};

  title = 'my-app works!';

}
```

**loggedinrouter.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, Attribute, ResolvedReflectiveProvider, ViewContainerRef, ComponentRef, ComponentFactory } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterOutletMap } from '@angular/router'
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router/src/directives/router_outlet';

@Directive({
  selector: 'router-outlet'
})
export class LoggedInRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet{
  publicRoutes: any;

  constructor(routerOutletMap: RouterOutletMap, _location: ViewContainerRef, name: string) {
    super(routerOutletMap, _location, name);

    // The Boolean following each route below 
    // denotes whether the route requires authentication to view
    this.publicRoutes = {
      'login': true,
      'signup': true
    };
  }

  load(factory: ComponentFactory<any>, providers: ResolvedReflectiveProvider[], outletMap: RouterOutletMap) {
    // DO AUTH CHECK HERE

    return super.load(factory, providers, outletMap);
  }

}
```

The problem I'm having is that since name is not an acceptable attribute for the @Routes decorator path objects, I can't get the path or name of the route that's calling the RouterOutlet.

Comment: I'm still getting same error and also where should i put "ComponentInstruction"

Comment: Do I need to add it as a provider to my AppComponent ? thats probs what this error is related too? " No provider for RouterOutletMap!"

Comment: I pasted your code in and looks like its missing something from the app component

Comment: Thanks, my app component is same as yours and so is my interceptor e.g. your loggedinrouter. ButI get same error. Maybe its the boot.ts file?

Comment: Where did you provide `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`?

Comment: import { Routes , Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router';

This is the lib version:  "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",